# Unfortunately, "appname" has stopped

Tags: android

I've completed and managed to install the app (i'm following a tutorial), but when running it on the emulator or real device, it gives me the error message, Unfortunately,  has stopped.

Log cat

```
11-27 09:57:54.669: I/Process(1373): Sending signal. PID: 1373 SIG: 9
11-27 09:58:08.729: D/AndroidRuntime(1397): Shutting down VM
11-27 09:58:08.729: W/dalvikvm(1397): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught              exception (group=0xb3aa4b90)
11-27 09:58:08.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1397): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-27 09:58:08.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1397): Process: com.davidgassner.plainolnotes,   PID: 1397
11-27 09:58:08.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1397): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to  instantiate activity   ComponentInfo{com.davidgassner.plainolnotes/com.davidgassner.plainolnotes.Quick_Note_Taker}  : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.davidgassner.plainolnotes.Quick_Note_Taker" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.davidgassner.plainolnotes-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.davidgassner.plainolnotes-2, /system/lib]]
11-27 09:58:08.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2102)
11-27 09:58:08.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
11-27 09:58:08.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-27 09:58:08.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
11-27 09:58:08.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-27 09:58:08.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-27 09:58:08.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
11-27 09:58:08.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-27 09:58:08.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-27 09:58:08.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
11-27 09:58:08.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
11-27 09:58:08.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-27 09:58:08.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1397): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.davidgassner.plainolnotes.Quick_Note_Taker" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.davidgassner.plainolnotes-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.davidgassner.plainolnotes-2, /system/lib]]
11-27 09:58:08.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
11-27 09:58:08.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
11-27 09:58:08.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
11-27 09:58:08.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
11-27 09:58:08.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2093)
11-27 09:58:08.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     ... 11 more
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.davidgassner.plainolnotes"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="13"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label=" Quick Note Taker"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="Quick_Note_Taker"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".NoteEditorActivity"/>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Could anyone help me figure out what the root of the problem is? If anything else is needed, tell me.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Is Quick_Note_Taker defined as an Activity in your manifest? Have you tried a clean and rebuild?

Comment: Yep, it is defined as an activity. I've already tried a clean and rebuild.

Comment: Have you added all the classes in manifest ?

Comment: Should be, I've uplaoded it. Maybe I'm missing something? Sorry, I'm just starting out.

Comment: Manifest looks okay. Whereabouts within your source code is this class file found? Can you confirm that it is at this path within your project: src/com/davidgassner/plainolnotes/Quick_Note_Taker.java

Comment: Try giving package name before activity name in Manifest declaration of activity.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There is no Quick_Note_Taker.java there, but there is both MainActivity.java (which I assume is the direct replacement for that).Can you elaborate on this furthur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your manifest (amongst other things) defines what Activites your app uses. One of those activities will be marked as the one to be started by the launcher. In this case it is:

```
<activity
    android:name="Quick_Note_Taker"
```

So Android will attempt to instantiate an instance of Quick_Note_Taker.java. It will look for this class within the APK in a path equivalent to this one in your source code: src/com/davidgassner/plainolnotes/. Within Eclipse, that is the same as what is shown under the path ProjectName/src/com.davidgassner.plainolnotes/ in Package Explorer.

You say that you have no file named Quick_Note_Taker.java, hence this error. You do however have a file called MainActivity.java which is the default Activity class created for you when you create a new Android Application Project. When you created your project, you could/should have changed this to Quick_Note_Taker instead of MainActivity. But that's not a big deal.

You could replace MainActivity with a class file called Quick_Note_Taker instead. Or the easy (and perfectly valid) option is to change the activity name from Quick_Note_Taker to ActivityMain in the manifest.